# How to convert uptime to datetime?

Tags: python, linux, time

I am working with an API that returns system uptime of certain events to me, which looks something like that:

```
8185.16
```

I would like to convert it to unix time to be able to tell when this event happened out of scope of this current machine. Problem is that I can't seem to find any existing code that does that.

I've tried just writing a function that calculates the delta between unix time and uptime to than apply it to all measurements. It looks like that:

```
def uptime():
    with open('/proc/uptime') as f:
        uptime = float(f.read().split()[0])
        now = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
        return uptime, now, now - uptime
```

Problem is, though, that it doesn't work fast enough, creating up to 10ms of inaccuracy, which I'd much rather avoid. For example in between those two runs delta varies from 1604944228.561784 to 1604944228.5529969, which is 8.7ms

```
In [252]: time uptime()
CPU times: user 1.26 ms, sys: 209 µs, total: 1.47 ms
Wall time: 1.67 ms
Out[252]: (8625.91, 1604952854.471784, 1604944228.561784)

In [250]: time uptime()
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 1.57 ms, total: 1.57 ms
Wall time: 1.25 ms
Out[250]: (8624.89, 1604952853.442997, 1604944228.5529969)
```

Is there existing code that could give me more reliable results or are there any other approaches that would be faster for this issue?

At the moment I'm running this 10000 times and using average of those 10000 values, but it just doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: But.. you don't need to read uptime on each measurement. You only need to read it _once_, to calculate when the computer booted up. Then add the event timestamp to the boot-timestamp and you'll get when the event happened. So your event happened at `8185.16 + psutil.boot_time()`.

Comment: @KamilCuk That is correct. I will only calculate this once. I'm showing two different results because running it several times could produce results varying by 10ms. This means if I'm out of luck, all of the calculations would be shifted by 10ms, which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: @KamilCuk and unfortunately I cannot use psutil.boot_time() as it will only return seconds, not ms. So this way accuracy loss would be much higher.

Comment: On linux there is `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` from `clock_gettime` - it should be the fastest.